# Doctrine - Packets out of Order

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

At the moment I am trying to deploy an application made with Symfony and Doctrine. While the application itself works fine, my MySQL database keeps responding with a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`-error.

I've checked my max_allowed_packet and wait_timeout variables on my MySQL-database and they are both set at a valid number to run the packets.

But when I run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status` the following error is added:

```
In PDOConnection.php line 27:
  Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 45. Packet size=4739923
```

Again, that packet size can pass through my set max_allowed_package setting. In other posts about this error message I found that PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES should be added to the database config. But I have only been able to find posts explaining how to do this in standard PHP or Laravel.

My question is this; how do I fix the Packets out of order issue in Doctrine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question today. I am using a shared hosting service and was trying to connect to the shared MySQL-database as a whole instead of just connecting to my part. After changing my database URL from:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@server_adress(like 123.4.5.6)/my_db"
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@localhost/my_db"
```

my application started working and I connected to my database.